# Received empty response from zabbix agent, assumes agent dropped connection

Tags: zabbix

Received empty response from zabbix agent at `[192.168.4.112]`, assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permission.

I have the iptables **off** and the selinux **disabled**.
The `zabbix_agentd.conf` has the right Server IP，and there is nothing in the `zabbix_agentd.log`.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question. It's also not very clear what you're asking. Please check out other sites such as Unix/Linux or Server Fault, and read the help files before asking.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely does not have the right IP.

- check the file for this parameter being defined more than once (also through the includes)
- check the line/address for any typos
- set agent DebugLevel to 4 and verify that agent sees the incoming connections from the address you expect

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem by rewrite the parameter in the zabbix_agentd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I have salved the question by rewirte the `zabbix_agentd.conf`.

Because both of the vps are on internet outside and have the public iP .

A is the server and B makes up the agent.

What I do not realize is that there are multiple IP for A (the zabbix_server). So the IP that I do write in the `zabbix_agentd.conf` is wrong.
How can I find it? I `telnet B_IP:10050` from A and `netstat -an | grep 10050` on the B. Then I find out  the solution.

```
######zabbix_agentd.conf#######

****
Server=119.XXX.XXX.43;119.xxx.xxx.46
****
#####zabbix_agentd.conf########
```

Excuse me, my englis is so-so and before the mismathc IP are find out I have check the iptables, selinux etc.